# Adding an orgchart/tree diagram to my website

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I am making a web app and I want to use a diagram of some sort to display the hierarchy of certain company members and display "lower ranked members" assigned to a higher ranked member. I was recently using a library called orgchart https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Pricing up until they decided to charge insane prices which makes sense because it is a really well built library. However, I do not have the funding for it. How would any of you recommend me to implement an orgchart into my code so that it is responsive and will not go out of my screen, and if it does, so that it is easy to scroll through.

Kind regards.